# Lookup not working

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a multiple lookup's (1 per state division) and the first one is working but not the others and I cannot figure out for the life of me why. Any suggestions where to look.

In the code snippet below the first one works but the second does not. I pass both (actually there is 6) as parameters to a custom code function yet the report shows #Error in the textbox after I click on the View Report button. I separated out the lookup's into dummy textbox's, the first one works the second shows #Error.

```
=Lookup(Parameters!NDEVDivisionalModelID.Value, Fields!DivModel_ID.Value, Fields!DivModel_Name.Value, "NDEVExtras")

=Lookup(Parameters!NSWDivisionalModelID.Value, Fields!DivModel_ID.Value, Fields!DivModel_Name.Value, "NSWExtras")
```

The parameters and query behind the datasets are identical except for obviously the filter on the state and both parameters bind there Available values to the respective dataset.

For NSW the dataset query is:

```
SELECT 0 AS DivModel_ID,
       NULL AS FinYearEnd,
       '(None)' AS DivModel_Name
WHERE  'NSW' NOT IN (@StateDivisionID)

UNION

SELECT D.ID AS DivModel_ID, 
       D.FinYearEnd, 
       D.Name AS DivModel_Name
FROM DivModel D INNER JOIN States S ON D.StateID = S.ID
WHERE s.Name = 'NSW' AND 
      s.Name IN (@StateDivisionID) AND
      D.FinYearEnd <> -1
ORDER BY FinYearEnd DESC, DivModel_Name
```

There is nothing complicated here and I cannot see my own probably a silly mistake. If it was a spelling mistake say then I am certain the report would not save so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I just forgot to set the data-type of the other parameters it was left as Text, should have been Integer as my ID's are integers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the where clause does not make sense:

```
WHERE s.Name = 'NSW' AND 
      s.Name IN (@StateDivisionID) AND 
      D.FinYearEnd <> -1
```

you have:

```
s.Name = 'NSW'
```

but also

```
s.Name IN (@StateDivisionID)
```

should you have the following:

```
WHERE (s.Name = 'NSW' OR 
          s.Name IN (@StateDivisionID)) AND 
          D.FinYearEnd <> -1
```

this is if you want to include NSW in all lookup results. Else I would have done the following:

```
WHERE     s.Name IN (@StateDivisionID) AND 
          D.FinYearEnd <> -1
```

Comment: To answer your question this is SQL within Report Builder so note the syntax for multi-valued parameters works conveniently using the IN operator. Anyhow my StateDivisionID has 6 values and is multi-valued and I also have 6 DivisionalModelID parameters one per state. If I select say NSW then the NSWDivisionalModelID has values otherwise it has a single value of "(None)"